# How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY for multiple entries?

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

In a single entry, we can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to `UPDATE` the value:

```
INSERT INTO table
(title, number) VALUES ('$title', '$amount')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number=number+$amount
```

How to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY for multiple entries as

```
INSERT INTO table
(title, number) VALUES 
('$title1', '$amount1'), 
('$title2', '$amount2'),
('$title3', '$amount3')
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the values clause:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   number = values(number),
   title = values(title)
```

Comment: how to add `$amount1`, `$amount2`, `$amount3` .... (the values come out of PHP) to the current values of the columns?

Comment: @Ali: sorry, I don't do PHP, why don't you try something like `number = number + values(number)`

Comment: That's it! How could be so blind not to see this! Thanks for clarification.